# joomla menu and subnav one template

Tags: joomla

I have a joomla template with index.php that includes mainmenu and subnav modules like below. The resulting html page renders the mainmenu in one div and the subnav in another div. I want to modify the template such that every mainmenu li element contains its subnav items. Motiv is I am styling the website for tablet and mobile and need to restructure some html.

`<div id="mainmenu"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" /></div>`

`<div id="subnav"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="subnav" /></div>`

You see! two seprate module inclusion or positions or call it what you like. How can I iterate over the menu items and its subitems and render it as I want. Will this break the access to menu from the admin panel?

Thanks a lot!

Muchtar

Comment: Joomla menu module itself provide functionality to show submenu in li (You need to create submenu in menu section). why you are using two modules?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I solved it in the configuration as u said plus some CSS.